# use output from alias command as filename to open in vi

Tags: 10.04, tty, ls, pipe, vi

I set up an alias this morning to help finding the latest log file in a directory. My alias looks like

```
alias latest="ls -lat | grep ^- | awk '{print \$8}' | head -1"
```

In my research so far this morning I've read a [blog - ParsingLS](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) which tells me this is probably not the best way to do it - let's ignore that for now, I can look at making a better alias using `find` later. For now assume I have a perfectly working command expected to output a filename from the current directory.

I thought I was going to be able to do `latest | vi`, to open the latest modified file in the directory, but it seems this won't work - vi complains that the output is not a terminal. I saw a stackoverflow question which suggested the issue is related to subshells and piping and so tried

```
latest | vi < `tty` > `tty`
```

But that just gets me

```
`tty`:ambiguous redirect
```

I'm sure there's something basic I am not getting about pipes here - I only recently started trying to use them in earnest, any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simple. If `latest` produces a filename on `stdout`, `$()` is the answer:

```
vim $( latest )
```

See `man bash`.

Comment: *facepalm* I dunno how I managed to miss this - I use that syntax all over the place in scripts, but never even thought of it 'at the prompt'. Thanks very much, this works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I assume a pager is not sufficient?

I don't think vi has support for this (at least not nvi or recent FreeBSD vi), vim does however:

```
latest | vim -
```

One workaround is to use a named pipe:

```
mkfifo vi.fifo
latest > vi.fifo & vi vi.fifo
rm vi.fifo
```

Not very pretty and FreeBSD vi seems to need an extra `:e` before it reads the fifo.

Comment: Pagers were worth me finding out about, even if I went Waltinator's way here. Thanks for the answer